# Ignore mysql_query SELECT

Tags: php

I'm using fopen and fwrite to create a new php file, but it's returning an error at the line of a query, specifically on SELECT:

```
<?php
# set $defaultDir, $fileName and $userID

$fileContent = "<?php
\$getBlogPostQ = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM posts WHERE id_users='".\$userID."' LIMIT 1");
?>";

$createFile = fopen($defaultDir . "/" . $fileName . ".php","a");
fwrite($createFile,$fileContent);
fclose($createFile);

?>
```

I know that the backslash escape the variable, but how can i avoid the execution of the "SELECT" to write it at the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Caution against the use of mysql_query as this method of access is no longer supported and will eventually be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use single quotes like this:

```
$fileContent = '<?php $getBlogPostQ = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM posts WHERE id_users=\'' . $userID . '\' LIMIT 1"); ?>';
```

Comment: Thanks, simple but effective!

Answer (score 0):

Just add backslash to escape double quotes too.

```
$fileContent = "<?php
\$getBlogPostQ = mysql_query(\"SELECT name FROM posts WHERE id_users='\".\$userID.\"' LIMIT 1\");
?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique more and more now, maybe you will like that too:

```
$fileContent = <<<ANYTHINGYOUWANT
<?php
 $getBlogPostQ = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM posts WHERE id_users='".$userID."' LIMIT 1");
?>
ANYTHINGYOUWANT;
```